# How do I print the string of <h> tag that has multiple <strong>?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, jupyter-notebook

```
firstHeader = mclarenHTML.find_all(re.compile('^h[2]'))[0] #finding header titles
print(firstHeader)
```

Output

```
<h2><strong><strong>1950-1953: </strong>Formula 1 begins: the super-charger years</strong></h2>
```

How do i get the string "1950-1953:Formula 1 begins: the super-charger years"?

Tried using `.string` but it returns none

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `.text`:

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(
    "<h2><strong><strong>1950-1953: </strong>Formula 1 begins: the super-charger years</strong></h2>",
    "html.parser",
)

header = soup.h2

print(header.text)
```

Prints:

```
1950-1953: Formula 1 begins: the super-charger years
```

---

Or use `.get_text()` - you can use then `strip=` and `separator=` parameters:

```py
print(header.get_text(strip=True, separator=" "))
```

Prints:

```
1950-1953: Formula 1 begins: the super-charger years
```